# Time complexity for nested while loop problem

Tags: data-structures

Hi community i am currently having issues understanding this data structures problem:

```
function Prob(n):
  x = 0
  i = 5
  while i <= n ^ 2 * sqrt(n) do:
    j = n * logbase5(n)             // In my solution for first iteration K i set everything equal to c
    while j >= 3 do:       // So far my solution is T(n) is in theta (n^2.5) but i don't think it's right.
                        // Iteration 1 K=nlog(n), Iteration 2 B=log(n).
      x = x + i - j
      j = j - 5
    end while
    i = 3 * i
  end while
  return x
end function
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @PaulH a type of pseudo-code, it doesn't matter at all to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's observe two things here:

1. `j` is only effected by `n`, so its value is the same each run of the loop: `n * logbase5(n)` but divide it by 5 (because we are getting `-5` each run. so it `theta (n * log (n))` (notice that `logbase5(n)` is just to get you confused, since it is: `log(n) / log(5)` which is a constant, the `-5` is also not changing the asymptotic behavior of this function).
2. `i` is changed in the outer loop by `i = i * 3`, but not in the inner loop. The upper bound is `(n ^ 2) * sqrt(n)` which is `n ^ 2.5` as you have noted, but, each iteration we ***triple*** `i`, by `i = 3 * i`. Thus, this loop is happening `logbase3(n ^ 2.5)` (because `i = 3 ^ # of iteration` more or less). Again, `logbase3(n) = log(n) / log(3)` ***and*** `log(n ^ m) = m * log (n)`, so we get again: `theta(log(n))`

All in all, we get `theta(log(n) * log(n))` or `theta(log^2 (n))`

**Remark** - I'm using the *CS log* (meaning in base 2), this is the common notation, and as you can see, it only differs in a constant factor from any other non-variable base.

Comment: Thank you! j being affected by n really threw me off

Comment: really quick follow up, did you multiply the inner loop theta by the outer loop theta to get theta^2?

Comment: @Lifeofnaye I hope this is what you have asked, I multiply the amount of *work* the inner loop does, in the amount of times the outer loop is being executed (since it doesn't do anything that it time consuming, other than the inner loop). Thus, I get the `log(n) * log(n)`

Comment: Yes that is correct, just to clarify we don't use the geometric series to solve this problem because j is only effected by n?

Comment: @Lifeofnaye Actually, I'm not looking at this as geometric sequence. The inner loop is predetermined by the input `n`, therefore, the number of loops doesn't relate to `i` at all. `i` **does** increase in a *"geometric"* way, but all we need to know is **when** the loop condition is being violated. In sequence terminology, which element is the first to violate the loop condition. You can test it on your own and see that this happens in the element in position of `theta(log(n))`.